# Give a sufficient condition for the general monic quadratic polynomial $f(X)=X^2+bX+c∈\mathbb Z[X]$ to have solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, hensels-lemma

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Combine Hensel’s lemma and quadratic
>   reciprocity to give a sufficient condition for the general monic quadratic polynomial $$f(X) = X^2 +bX +c ∈\mathbb Z[X]$$ with integer coefficients to have solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Hensel's Lemma tells us that for a polynomial $f ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ with integer coefficients, $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 < n$ and $x ∈ Z$ such that

$f(x) = 0$ mod $p^n$ and  $f'(x)\neq 0$ mod $p$, we get $y$ such that

$y = x$ mod $p^n$, $f(y) = 0$ mod $p^{n+1}$, and $f'(y)= 0$ mod $p$.

Does that mean that the sufficient condition is simply that $f(x) = 0$ mod $p^n$ and  $f'(x)\neq 0$ mod $p$ ?

I am confused. How does that indicate that there is a solution?

Comment: Sounds like you have seen the statement of Hensel's lemma. So when might the lifting process fail? What does that imply when applied to quadratic polynomials in particular?

Comment: But I've only seen it in a Number Theory course, not in Abstract Algebra. So I'm lost and when I try to find it online I become even more confused because all I can find are explanations which use algebra

Comment: Which version exactly are you familiar with?

Comment: I don't know. I was just told that it "resembles Newton's Method" from Calculus, which I do know, but beyond that I am fairly lost and not sure where to find help.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $b=c=0$...

Comment: Why? How can I understand and prove the condition?

Comment: Servaes, that was a bit cruel :-)

Comment: So that's a trivial solution then..

Comment: Well, if the exercise is to check what Hensel's lemma says about solvability of a congruence don't you think that you should first familiarize yourself with what Hensel's lemma is all about. If you have not covered this in class, then it would be highly cruel to assign this exercise. Anyway, if I post what I think is the desired answer, seeing it will not help you unless you know what Hensel's lemma states.

Comment: I understand it as I need to assume $f(a_0) \equiv 0 $(mod$p$) and $f ' (a_0) \not\equiv 0 $(mod $p$). Then there exists some $h(x) \in (\mathbb{Z} / p^n\mathbb{Z})[X]$ such that $ g(x) - g(h) - (x - h) g'(b) = ( x - b)^2 h(x)$.  Is this correct and what do I do from here?

Comment: Could you help me understand Hensel's Lemma then? From a number theory perspective that doesn't rely on too much algebra please?

Comment: Is the sufficient condition that $f(x) = 0$ mod $p^n$ and $f(x) = 0 $mod $(p^k)$ but $f'(x) \neq 0 $ mod $(p^{k+1})$?

Comment: I've changed my question a bit

Comment: Ok, you notice that the condition about the derivative (at the zero) stays the same throughout when lifting. Therefore to ge the process started it sufficesto check what happens when $n=1$ (= the base case of induction, really!!).

Comment: And the other connection you are expected to make is: what can you say about a zero $a$ of a polynomial $f(x)$, is you know that both $f(a)$ and $f'(a)$ vanish?

Comment: Hmm, when n equals 1 I can see that it either does or doesn't have a solution based on the quadratic reciprocity of $(-c - (b/2))^2)$ but I could be really off-base here.

Comment: That's a good start! And if that quantity happens to be zero modulo $p$, then...

Comment: If that quantity equals zero modulo $p$, then I know that there exists some y which is a quadratic residue modulo $p^n$, which I think indicates that X is a quadratic residue modulo $p^n$?